# Python Pandas condition fails to identify rows accurately

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, data-science

This is a input and output from a jupyter notebook. I need help with identifying the reason why I am unable to accurately select and set the data in the 'went_out' column.

[image]

Both the red underline cells are supposed to be displaying data from the datetime column of its own row but only one is accurately displaying it. It turns out that many of the rows that matched my condition did not get selected and set.

[image]

This is a sample of the code I used:

```html
# your answer here
df.loc[(df['reading_type'] == 'motion') & (df['value'] == 255), 'event'] = 'motion on'
df.loc[(df['reading_type'] == 'motion') & (df['value'] == 0), 'event'] = 'motion off'

df2 = df.loc[(df['reading_type'] == 'door') | (df['event'] == 'motion on')].copy()
df2.loc[(df['event'] == 'door close') & (df['event'].shift(-1) == 'door open'), 'went_out'] = df2['datetime']
df2
```

Here are the links for the jupyter notebook file and csv file:

1. Jupyter Notebook:
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/15f6NQrM4UoAZlzRhK35TOKyhPJnmWWdU/view?usp=sharing
2. CSV file:
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hZudSVbT91ESj2qkzrJ--CbVdrzVCmce/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you try with `df2.loc[( (df['event'] == 'door close') & (df['event'].shift(-1) == 'door open') ), 'went_out'] = df2['datetime']`. I have added the selection condition to one () instead of 2 separate ones.

Comment: @manoj Nope I just tried it and it still gives the same output.

Comment: @Benjamincan you please provide sample data(in csv) so I can test it locally.

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara Okay I've added the google drive links at the bottom of the post.

Comment: I just realised I've made a mistake. I should have done the conditioning on df2 instead of df. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understood you are trying to write the date and time when the door closes. This might be a part of the solution that you want. Instead of looking for the the condition of door opening and then closing you can use just the door close condition to index the 'went_out' column.

```
df.loc[(df['reading_type'] == 'door') & (df['value'] == 255), 'event'] = 'door on'
df.loc[(df['reading_type'] == 'door') & (df['value'] == 0), 'event'] = 'door off'

df2 = df[df['reading_type'] == 'door'].copy()
# The line below is modified
df2.loc[df2['event'] == 'door off', 'went_out'] = df2[df2['event'] == 'door off']['datetime']
print(df2)
```

The output looks like:

```
    id  datetime    device  location    reading_type    value   event   went_out
284 284 2018-01-01 07:57:56 Door    door    door    255.0   door on NaN
285 285 2018-01-01 07:58:12 Door    door    door    0.0 door off    2018-01-01 07:58:12
294 294 2018-01-01 08:29:25 Door    door    door    255.0   door on NaN
295 295 2018-01-01 08:29:38 Door    door    door    0.0 door off    2018-01-01 08:29:38
357 357 2018-01-01 09:16:38 Door    door    door    255.0   door on NaN
361 361 2018-01-01 09:17:40 Door    door    door    0.0 door off    2018-01-01 09:17:40
```

Hope this is helpful.

**Edit**
Condition to get date and time when there is door close after door open

```
df2.loc[((df2['event'].shift(-1) == 'door on') & (df2['event']=='door off') ), 'went_out'] = df2[df2['event']=='door off']['datetime']

print(df2[df2['event'] == 'door off'])

    id  datetime    device  location    reading_type    value   event   went_out
285 285 2018-01-01 07:58:12 Door    door    door    0.0 door off    2018-01-01 07:58:12
295 295 2018-01-01 08:29:38 Door    door    door    0.0 door off    NaN
361 361 2018-01-01 09:17:40 Door    door    door    0.0 door off    2018-01-01 09:17:40
509 509 2018-01-01 15:50:46 Door    door    door    0.0 door off    2018-01-01 15:50:46
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes that is right. But the thing is that, sometimes the door is closed but there are still 'motion on' which means there are activities happening in the house.

Resident can sometimes close the door but still be in the house. So I look for:
1. Door close
2. There must not be motions between door close and door open
3. Door open (coming home)

Comment: Door Close -> Door Open == Left home and come home. Door Close -> Motion On -> Door Open == Close door but still at home.

Comment: Check the Edit solution.

Comment: Thanks. By the way it's door open after door close. Seems to work. I will try it when I get home and I'll post here if it works :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. After seeing your code, it made me realised that I've been doing the conditioning on df instead of df2. I've made that change and it works now.

Comment: I am glad I could help :). For the solution I have the feeling that when we are setting the value it should be   `df2[((df2['event'].shift(-1) == 'door on') & (df2['event']=='door off') )]['datetime']`  instead, since we only want to set 'went_out' for the indexes which match both the condition. What do you think?